# LoaderLock was detected in multithreaded C# application

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I am writing a WinForms application in C#.

At one point in the application, I spawn a new STA thread (create thread, then `SetApartmentState`) that creates a new form and then shows it with plain old `Show()`. The form itself contains only a docked `DataGrid` whose `DataSource` points to a `DataTable` retrieved from a newly open `SqlConnection`. All data and UI objects are created on the same thread.

When I execute that code I get a `LoaderLock` exception with the following (helpful) text:

> Attempting managed execution inside OS
>   Loader lock. Do not attempt to run
>   managed code inside a DllMain or image
>   initialization function since doing so
>   can cause the application to hang.

I'm doing no such thing, at least not intentionally! The stack trace has only unmanaged code at the head and I'm unable to debug that with C# Express 2008.

Looking around the Internets, people usually just disable that exception within VisualStudio. Is this another case of Microsoft being padantic, or should I actually spend time figuring out what's going on?

**Update** The error seemed to be caused by opening **multiple** forms (each with data grid, etc.) rapidly. If I switch the `Show()` to `ShowDialog()` and view the forms one at a time, then the error goes away.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this before when using P/Invoke with a DLL which wasn't built quite right. I think we ascertained that it wasn't dangerous in our particular case and would take more effort to fix than to disable the warning.

Do you have any native code in your app?

Comment: We've had this warning as well. It caused rare hangs in the debugger - but no other problem that we've seen.

Comment: No native code at all. Hopefully, once I get back to the office I'll be able to track down the unmanaged call stack.

Comment: Just adding info to an old Q&A here. Someone else had the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889736/why-am-i-getting-the-loaderlock-was-detected-warning-when-debugging/889953). I'm seeing this while using VS2010SP1 to debug a Excel addin ... speaking of "a DLL which wasn't built quite right". :)  Based on general wisdom I'm going to flag VS to ignore these errors, at least while I'm working on this project. Thanks to the OP and others providing info here.

Answer (score 2):

I've experienced this when working with Managed DirectX. My solution was to disable the Loader Lock debugging assistant, although this might not be the best solution for *every* case.  It certainly was not a problem with production code.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this exact problem before now with multi-threading C# forms.  It was a while back so I'm struggling to remember the details, but I recall the issue was related to performing operations on forms or controls by a thread which doesn't own them -- E.g. calling Show() from the wrong thread.  If you pass a message to the owning thread and get it to handle such operations then that might solve your problem.

Comment: I'm very careful about my multithreading. In this case, the thread does not communicate at all with other threads so I am pretty confident that cross thread communication is not the issue here.