# LoaderLock Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql-server-2012, sqlconnection

I'm facing a problem for connecting to my database .I wanna connect to one of my sqlserver's DB and I use `SqlConnection` but when I open my database connection there's an error with this title **"LoaderLock was detected"** and this message :

**"Attempting managed execution inside OS Loader lock. Do not attempt to run managed code inside a DllMain or image initialization function since doing so can cause the application to hang."**

and here's the code :

```
{
    SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DB1;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand scom = new SqlCommand(@"insert into t1 values(2,'Daniel')", sc);
    sc.Open();
    scom.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sc.Close(); 
}
```

Please help me through this problem,what am I missing here ? and what should I do?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56642/loader-lock-error and http://stackoverflow.com/a/889802/1179471